# Screen flickers when opening/closing apps in wayland

Tags: wayland, 21.04, flicker

I am using **Ubuntu 21.04**, with **AMD Ryzen 5** processor and **RX 560X** graphic card.

When I **open/close** any app (Brave,VSCode,Slack etc) **screen flicker** with a delay of 1 sec it only happens in wayland never in xorg.

It happens when I use any app which uses **X-Wayland**

Kindly help to solve this issue.